# Type assignment error in typed reducer callback

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The below code is giving me the following type error

> No overload matches this call.
>     Overload 1 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: TestData, currentValue: TestData, currentIndex: number, array: TestData[]) => TestData, initialValue: TestData): TestData', gave the following error.
>       Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'TestData'.
>     Overload 2 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: BooleanObject, currentValue: TestData, currentIndex: number, array: TestData[]) => BooleanObject, initialValue: BooleanObject): BooleanObject', gave the following error.
>       Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'BooleanObject'.

is anyone able to help explain why the type is not assignable?

In my mind, in the TestState interface, I defined the property 'booleanObject' to be of type BooleanObject and BooleanObject is an interface which defines a string index property such that when indexed with a string the return value's type should be a boolean.

Then by casting the initial value in the reducer to type BooleanObject,

a) the reducer returns the correct type expected for property 'booleanObject' in the state definition and

b) then when I index the accumulator (of type BooleanObject) I believe I should be expecting the accumulator["index"] value is of type boolean

Where am I lacking to work out why I'm getting a type not assignable error?

Thanks in advance!

```
import React from 'react';

interface TestProps {
    data: TestData[];
}

interface TestState {
    booleanObject: BooleanObject;
}

interface BooleanObject {
    [index: string]: boolean;
}

interface TestData {
    name: string;
    subData: SubData[];
}

interface SubData {
    name: string;
    value: string;
}

class Test extends React.Component<TestProps, TestState>{
    constructor(props: TestProps){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            booleanObject: this.props.data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator[currentValue.name] = false, {} as BooleanObject)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your types look okay.

Basically, in your `reduce`, when you are returning `accumulator[currentValue.name] = false;` which means you are returning false(i.e. boolean) and hence the issue.

Just properly return in the reduce callback and your types will be fixed.

**Like this**

```js
import React from "react";

interface TestProps {
  data: TestData[];
}

interface TestState {
  booleanObject: BooleanObject;
}

interface BooleanObject {
  [index: string]: boolean;
  //   index: boolean;
}

interface TestData {
  name: string;
  subData: SubData[];
}

interface SubData {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}

class Test extends React.Component<TestProps, TestState> {
  constructor(props: TestProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      booleanObject: this.props.data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        accumulator[currentValue.name] = false;
        return accumulator;
      }, {} as BooleanObject),
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Am I correct in saying that because I didn't explicitly return a BooleanObject typed object in my reducer callback it essentially was returning undefined which is evaluated to be false/boolean and was trying to assign it to the expected return type of the callback BooleanObject? Im still a little confused by how does javascript assume "return accumulator[currentValue.name] = false" is whats returned? I thought the callback would implicitly return the accumulator object with its assigned properties and type?

Comment: yes - you should return a BooleanObject ... doing  this`return accumulator[currentValue.name] = false"` will not return object, it returns false. You can check this by typing a simple line of code (eg: a = 2) in browser console and you will see that 2 is returned .... with javascript reduce , you will have to do accumulation logic based on the needs return the accumulator for each iteration...

Answer (score 0):

The type of `reduce` function is something like this

```
Array<T>.reduce(callbackfn: (previousValue: T, currentValue: T, ..) => T): T
```

meaning, it's result is of the type of elements of the array.

So, since `this.props.data` is of type `TestData[]`, `reduce` method must return a result of type `TestData` which is not the case in your code (which casts and returns `BooleanObject`).